# How to get the drawable from textview

Tags: android

I am trying to get the drawable Id from the textview. But I can not get the drawable Id from textview. So I get the drawable and convert into bitmap to check the drawable. It's working for png icons. But id I try with VectorDrawable I can not check it. Herewith I attached the code.

```
private void checkDrawable(int resourceId){
        Drawable[] drawables = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawables[0] ).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)textView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(resourceId)).getBitmap();
        return bitmap == bitmap2;
    }
```

This code is working fine. But if I change to VectorDrawable I can not check.

```
private void checkDrawable(int resourceId){
        Drawable[] drawables = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
        VectorDrawable bitmap = ((VectorDrawable)drawables[0]);
        VectorDrawable bitmap2 = ((VectorDrawable)textView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(resourceId));
        return bitmap == bitmap2;
    }
```

It returning different values. Please let me any idea to check the VectorDrawable images in textView.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the drawable Id from the textview.

I'll just address this directly.

You can create your own subclass of `TextView` that will parse its `AttributeSet` during inflation and retain this information for you. This will let you query it later at any time.

```
public class MyTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    private int drawableLeftId;
    private String drawableLeftEntry;

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
            if (attrs.getAttributeName(i).equals("drawableLeft")) {
                String attributeValue = attrs.getAttributeValue(i).substring(1);
                this.drawableLeftId = Integer.parseInt(attributeValue);
                this.drawableLeftEntry = getResources().getResourceEntryName(drawableLeftId);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getDrawableLeftId() {
        return drawableLeftId;
    }

    public String getDrawableLeftEntry() {
        return drawableLeftEntry;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this in your layout:

```
<com.example.stackoverflow.MyTextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_drawable"/>
```

And then you can retrieve the id and the name:

```
MyTextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);
int drawableLefId = text.getDrawableLeftId(); // 2131165284 (the actual value of R.drawable.my_drawable)
String drawableLeftEntry = text.getDrawableLeftEntry(); // "my_drawable"
```